# ColdFusion 9 LDAP

Tags: coldfusion, ldap

In our intranet application, if a user is not authenticated, I use the `CFNTAuthenticate` tag.

But, normally the user is already authenticated and I'm able to retrieve his username with `mid(cgi.REMOTE_USER, 8, 13)`. How can I retrieve his group memberships (or at least if he is member of a specific group) without having him to type his password (as he is already authenticated, single sign-on)?

I hope I was able to provide all required information for a simple answer from your side (in the hope there is a simple answer).

Comment: Instead of `mid(cgi.REMOTE_USER, 8, 13)` you should be using `ListLast(cgi.REMOTE_USER, "\")`, it's way more idiomatic and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Active Directory account to retrieve group memberships for other users. I have a ColdFusion-specific domain account for looking up group information. That account doesn't need any special permissions in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Checking a direct group membership is simple. Use this as the LDAP query (`<cfldap>`):

```
(&(samAccountName=#userAccount#)(memberOf=#distinguishedNameOfGroup#))
```

If turns up empty the user is not member of that group.

**Important:** The values of `userAccount` and `distinguishedNameOfGroup` must be escaped before you can use them in a filter. See the [Special Characters chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475.aspx#Special_Characters) on the MSDN page that explains the search filter syntax.

Checking a nested group membership (i.e., user is in a subgroup of the group you want to check) is comparatively complicated.

Comment: many thanks so far! Assuming the user is already authenticated, I'm able to retrieve username with ListLast(cgi.REMOTE_USER, "\"). Now, how can I use ldap tag withou having the user to type his password again?

Comment: ColdFusion does not support NTLM or NEGOTIATE authentication methods and Active Directory by default does not allow anonymous binds. Your best bet is to create an AD user account with next to no privileges which is just used for LDAP binding. Hard-code the user's DN and password in your `<cfldap>` call. Not pretty at all, but it works.